# Template type deduction according to constructor argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction

I have a class template whose constructor accepts a callable whose type is a template parameter. I would like to have that type deduced so I don't have to specify it whenever instantiating the class.

Unfortunately, the type deduction doesn't work in the example below. Is there a way to get it to work?

```
template<typename F>
class C {
public:
   C(F&& f) : m_f{f} {}
private:
   F m_f;
};

class D {
public:
    static int s() { return 0; }
private:
   C<decltype(&s)> c {&s}; // OK
   C<> c2 {&s};            // error, not enough template parameters
};
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/8cphYR7lCvBA8ro4

Note this is similar to [Can template parameter deduction be used in class data members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398358/can-template-parameter-deduction-be-used-in-class-data-members?noredirect=1&lq=1) but here I'm asking about getting something similar to work, not about standard compliance.

One more note is that while re-specifiying the type of the template parameter in the example above is just a non-DRY inconvenience (which one of the answers below suggests solving with a macro), I'm not sure how it would be possible to have an instance of `C` with `F` being a non-global lambda function type (e.g. one that's defined on the spot), in case that instance is a data member. A technique which would allow that would be very powerful and useful, IMHO.

Comment: Crux of the matter is this being a member variable. Member means no deduction.

Comment: @StoryTeller The other question is of course super relevant (it even mentions passing callables as the use case for this) but I'm not sure it's a duplicate - the other question asks whether this is standard behavior, not whether there is some way to get the deduction to work using some other technique.

Comment: `C<>` this syntax is for default template argument, not deduction.

Comment: @Danra - I see you point. I'll tell you what. I'll reopen, since you are indeed asking how to get around it. But I suggest you edit a mention of the other question in, or someone else may come here and close it again.

Comment: Try just `C`?  Or `auto c2=C{&s};`?  Doubtful, and lack C++17 usable compiler on phone so cannot check.

Comment: @Yakk Just `C` doesn't work and `auto` isn't allowed for data members.

Comment: @danra then you are out of luck; it is not permitted by the standard and obvious extensions the compiler could support don't work.

Answer (score 4):

If your main goal is to avoid typing `&s` twice, the pragmatic solution is to define a macro:

```
#define CC(name,value) decltype(C{value}) name{value}

class D {
public:
    static int s() { return 0; }
private:
    CC(c,&s);
    // lambda still not possible:
    // CC(c2,[](){return 42;});
};
```

Comment: If you're going to define a macro, the macro should be `decltype(C{value}) name{value}` - otherwise you're duplicating logic with the constructor, and you can't tell because it's hidden behind a macro.

Comment: @Barry What do you mean by "duplicating logic with the constructor"? Maybe share an example showing why the edited macro is better?

Comment: @Danra The macro assumes that `C{x}` deduces as `C<decltype(x)>`. That's not necessarily going to be permanently true.

Comment: @Barry That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
decltype(C{&s}) c{&s};
```

But I'm not aware of a way to avoid duplicating the `&s`.