# Why this nested template deduction should fail?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

When I was playing with templates, I noticed a strange template deduction fail and I like to know why this should fail logically. Please check this code:

```
template<typename T = int>
struct A {
    T v;
};

int main()
{
    A k;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(k.v), int>);
}
```

This code compiles without any problem and `k.v` will have `int` type because it is defined as default type of template argument. Now this code:

```
template<typename T = int>
struct A {
    T v;
};

struct B {
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    A k;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(k.v), int>);
}
```

This code gives compile error for `B`. Because it seems that argument deduction is not allowed in non-static struct member. But I don't understand why. Since `AAA` template has a default type, it can easily consider `A` member in `B` structure as `A<int>`. I like to know why this does not happen. Any idea?

Comment: I don't see a difference between your snippets apart from the unused class `B`... Am I blind?

Comment: @Quentin I have not used it. but it gives error :D it is a code to produce error and struct definition does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
struct B {
    A a;
};
```

gives an error:

```
invalid use of template-name 'A' without an argument list
```

That's because `A` is a template, and hence the compiler requires that you use it as such. This is true even if `A` has a default argument; you still have to use `<>` to denote that you are using a template.

So this piece of code:

```
struct B {
    A<> a;   // note the <>
};
```

will compile just fine.

As to *why* template parameters can't be deduced for non-static data members, it seems to be the same reason as why this doesn't work:

```
struct B {
  auto a = 0;  // error
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398358/can-template-parameter-deduction-be-used-in-class-data-members) question and answer for more details.

Comment: But it is not needed when we don't use it as a member of another class. This solves the problem, but I'm not sure why it should be needed.

Comment: @Afshin Hmm, I'm not sure *why*, actually.

Comment: @Afshin found an answer that addresses your question. I've edited it into the answer.