# Class template parameter type deduction inside another class scope

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have some type deduction guide issue with a simple class template, that is instantiated issues in the main function scope, but fails to do that inside another class.

Here is an example:

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
    X(T&)
    {
    }
};

struct User
{
    X x{1}; // error: invalid use of template-name 'X' without an argument list
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    auto x = X(i); // OK
    (void)x;
}
```

I am kind of puzzled, why is that and how this can be fixed.
Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, you are hoping that `X x{1}` deduces `X<int>`?

Comment: Your `X` constructor takes a `T&` instead of a `T`. That's an additional wrinkle that doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Clangd gives a more meaningful error message, which would have probably made easier for you (or me, or anyone else) to search the web for an answer,

```
Use of class template 'X' requires template arguments;
argument deduction not allowed in non-static struct member
```

and the reason for this is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398358/can-template-parameter-deduction-be-used-in-class-data-members).

Comment: better flag as duplicate instead of repeating answers that exist elsewhere. Nevermind, just saying

Comment: Yeah, probably the added value of clangd message could have been put in a comment.

Comment: indeed. OP already knows that it isnt allowed, question is why and how to fix. Though the error message is really interesting ;)

Comment: Since the OP asks _**I am kind of puzzled, why is that** and how this can be fixed?_, I think that my answer (before including in it the link to the duplicate) partly answers the question, no? I hope the interesting message will give more points :P